# High-Cardinality Categorical Values in ML.NET 0.11 for Multiclass Classification Model

Tags: ml.net

For ML.NET 0.11, the attribute `MLContext.Transforms.Categorical` seems to only have `OneHotEncoding` and `OneHotHashEncoding` as options for transforming categorical values to features. I have some data columns with high cardinality that might be better to use numerical representation instead. Do we have that options in ML.NET or do I need to preprocess the data externally first?

Answer (score 2):

You can convert them to [KeyType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.data.keytype?view=ml-dotnet) instead of numeric values.

```
var rnd = new Random();
var enumerable = Enumerable.Range(1, 1000)
                           .Select(n => new Row { Email = "sadas" + rnd.Next(1, 41) + "@so.com"
                                                  Label = rnd.Next(1, 6).ToString() });
var context = new MLContext();
var data = context.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(enumerable);
var pipeline = context.Transforms.Conversion.MapValueToKey(nameof(Row.Email));
var preview = pipeline.Fit(data).Transform(data).Preview(10);
```

Sample result:

```
| Email          | Email | Label | 
|----------------|-------|-------| 
| sadas25@so.com | 39    | 3     | 
| sadas7@so.com  | 1     | 4     | 
| sadas13@so.com | 10    | 1     | 
| sadas27@so.com | 33    | 4     | 
| sadas5@so.com  | 19    | 4     | 
| sadas31@so.com | 4     | 2     | 
| sadas2@so.com  | 38    | 4     | 
| sadas22@so.com | 25    | 2     | 
| sadas37@so.com | 36    | 5     | 
| sadas32@so.com | 26    | 2     |
```

Comment: One more follow up question: if we were to change it to KeyType, does it mean it wouldn't compute as part of the concatenation transform, right? Would that be better or worse (or depends) compare to just have large one-hot encoding?

Comment: You can concatenate them with other features. One hot should better when many rows share the same value. IDK your data, maybe you can clusterised your values for lowering the cardinality.

Comment: When I tried to do `mlContext.Transforms.Concatenate("Features",...,"MapValueToKeyFeature",...")` I got an error on `pipeline.Fit(data)` stating `System.InvalidOperationException: 'Column 'MapValueToKeyFeature' is key.Concatenation of keys is unsupported.'`. 

Am I missing a step to be able to concatenate this feature with the rest?

Comment: You are so right. My bad!  I've deduced from this sample: https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning-samples/tree/master/samples/csharp/getting-started/MatrixFactorization_ProductRecommendation but there is no concatenation. I think you can transform it again key to vector.  I am waiting for your results.

Comment: And, maybe you can use PCA. https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning-samples/tree/master/samples/csharp/getting-started/Clustering_CustomerSegmentation

Comment: I was considering clustering vs multi-class classification initially. Since the goal for this model is to make a predictor that can give one of the three known outcome labels, clustering wouldn't be a good approach, right?  

On the side note, is it correct to say that if we train a model for clustering, we do not need to do feature concatenate (based on the sample code on github you mentioned) and hence allow us to use `MapValueToKeyFeature` on the high cardinality categorical data column?